# How to use state in dynamically created components at runtime for React Native

Tags: reactjs, dynamic, runtime, state, render

I have created a function that creates and builds a tree of components at run time.
This tree is different every time based on some parameters coming from a webservice.
I am able to render the tree successfully, but the state values don't get updated when the state is changed.

For example:

```
export default class App extends React.Component {

  state={
    loading:true,
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.buildComponent();
  }

  buildComponent() {
    var comp = <View style={{flex:1,justifyContent:'center',alignItems:'center'}}>
      <Text>{this.state.name}</Text>
      <Button title="Change State" onPress={()=>this.setState({name:"Changed"})} />
    </View>
    this.comp = comp;
    this.setState({loading:false});
  }

  render() {
    if (this.state.loading) {
      return <Text style={{alignSelf:'center',marginTop:50}}>Loading ...</Text>
    }
    return (
     this.comp
    );
  }

}
```

In this code sample, I know it is not best practice to do it this way, but I just have a use case in which I need to code it in such way.

As you see in the sample, when I click on the button, I want the state name to be changed to "Changed", but it doesn't get changed.

Sounds like React doesn't map the state.name inside the text and renders it once it's changed.

I don't want to place the buildComponent inside render method because buildComponent does a lot of expensive calculations and calling it every time would affect the performance big time, therefore I wanted a way to build the components one time and render it, but state values don't get updated at all.

Thanks in advance for your valuable input.

Comment: Why not define `comp` in `render`?

Comment: I mentioned in my post, that I don't want to define the comp in render because I have a use case and it needs to be defined outside of the render.

Comment: I think you might be misunderstanding how react rendering works. The only way for something to read updated values is for those values to be defined inside render. That doesn't mean you need to perform the expensive calculations again. rendering in react is super cheap because of the virtual dom. can you show us an example of your "expensive calculation" ? can you just memoize it?

Comment: Thanks for your input. I really know how react rendering works. it's fast and super cheap. however, for my use case, I should render it exactly as the example above. thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

u are using componentDidMount so the comp only renders once when the state is updated componentDidMount is not called, so if u want to reRender comp again u def componentDidUpdate instead

```
 componentDidUpdate() {
    this.buildComponent();
  }
```

Comment: I think it's the same as putting it inside render() method. the reason for me not putting it there, is I don't want it to be rendered second time.

Comment: You don't want it to render again? What's the point of using `state` then. You may as well just hardcode the value